# Can we do Sun LDAP group and role administration using JSP

Tags: jsp, ldap

We are looking to build an interface to manage sun LDAP static/dynamic groups and roles.

Is this possible using JSP's?
Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Write yourself some beans that interact with your directory server using the UnboundID [LDAP SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) and connect your JSP to the beans using `<jsp:useBean` However, do not fall into the trap of using Java code in a JSP, it's bad form, but you know that.